# how do add a uibutton and position it at bottom of the UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

newbie question,

I have created a uitable programmatically, and need to add a submit button at bottom of the table, setting `mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(xxxx)` does not related to my table, any idea? This is my code for the uitable

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.view.bounds;

self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame
                                            style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

self.myTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |  
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.myTable];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just set it as the footerView for your table. Create the button normally, then add it as the footer view to your table

```
UIButton * b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[b setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(submitButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.myTable.tableFooterView = b;
```

You then just need to implement the `submitButtonClicked` function to do whatever you want when the button is clicked.

Comment: i end up with using - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section instead, but your idea was the inspiration. although I still don't know how to set button position directly in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

To place your button at the bottom of your tableView, try this:

```
UIButton *submit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[submit setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tableViewFrame.origin.y + tableViewFrame.size.height, 80, 80);
[[self view] addSubview:submit];
```

Comment: tks for the reply, however, that is actually what my problem is

Comment: if i setFrame.CGRectMake for anything over 500 in height, the button will disappear, looks like the position for my button is not related to the uitableview, it's more like static position in CSS
my tableview's height is longer than the screen..